# How to select a class by GetElementByClass and click on it programmatically

Tags: c#, html, ajax, browser, webbrowser-control

I have been trying to use this code to read the element by class in html/ajax knowing GetElementByClass is not a option in webBrowser.Document. I can't seem to get a return value then invoke the member. Is there a work around for this?

References:
[Getting HTMLElements by Class Name](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/7b14a98d-1c81-4ed3-9a1b-f829dbd5e1aa)

Example:

```
<span class="example">(<a href="http://www.test.com/folder/remote/api?=test" onclick=" return do_ajax('popup_fodder', 'remote/api?=test', 1, 1, 0, 0); return false; " class="example">test</a>)</span>
```

Example code:

```
   HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection = default(HtmlElementCollection);
   theElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
   foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
   {
        //If curElement.GetAttribute("class").ToString = "example"  It doesn't work.  
        // This should be the work around.
        if (curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("example"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(curElement.GetAttribute("InnerText")); // Doesn't even fire.
            // InvokeMember(test) after class is found.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

I admit it's not very intuitive but you need to use `GetAttribute("className")` instead of `GetAttribute("class")`

```
HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection = default(HtmlElementCollection);
theElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
{
    if (curElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString() == "example")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(curElement.GetAttribute("InnerText")); // Do something you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this is a example of how i used the webbrowser control to find class specific elements and invoke Click on a link inside.

simplified >

```
   foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("li"))
        {
            // use contains() if the class attribute is 
            // class="page_item page-item-218 current_page_item"
            //this to be more on spot! >> if (item.OuterHtml.Contains("class=\"page_item"))
            // or
            if (item.OuterHtml.Contains("page_item"))
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement childItem in item.Children)
                {
                    if (childItem.TagName == "A")
                    {
                        //Click the link/Current element
                        childItem.InvokeMember("Click");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

does this way work ?..

it works for me right here.

or maybe i misunderstand your question?

Comment: This does not fire the event in the Example link. I am trying to fire the ajax event "Test" if you take a look at the link again . =)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use qjuery's selector engine for this.
And also, where are you expecting the messagebox.show to appear ?

Comment: Awesome, a fork of jquery? ;)

Comment: Messagebox.Show was to show me the text that it retrieved. JQuery I am not familiar with. Got a example in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim HtmlElementcolltwo As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
        For Each eleme As HtmlElement In HtmlElementcolltwo
            ' Check the attributtes you want
            If eleme.GetAttribute("className") = "derrt_submit feed-zed-bff" Then
                'Check even the text if you want
                ' If elem.InnerText = "Sign In" Then
                'Invoke your event
                eleme.InvokeMember("click")
                'End If
            End If
        Next
```

This Also works instead of using "class" use "className"