# VB.NET/GetElementByClass how to div class click?

Tags: html, vb.net, click, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

```
</div></div></div><div class="f u" id="m_more_item"><a href="/browse/likes/?id=1026395497374065&amp;start=30&amp;refid=53"><span>Diğerlerini Gör</span></a></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

DOCUMENT

CODE:

```
Dim h1 As HtmlElementCollection = Nothing
    h1 = W.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In h1
        If InStr(curElement.GetAttribute("classname").ToString, "f u") Then

            curElement.InvokeMember("Click")
```

BUT code does not work HELP ME ?

Comment: IN WHAT WAY DOESNT WORK ?!?

Comment: "DOESN'T WORK" IS NOT AN ACCURATE PROBLEM DESCRIPTION.

Comment: ı want to class="f u" click .how can ı ?

Answer (score 0):

Off my Example: [VB.Net - select a class using GetElementByClass and then click the item programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933704/vb-net-select-a-class-using-getelementbyclass-and-then-click-the-item-programm/29391589#29391589)

The problem is your trying to click the DIV instead of trying to click the A HREF tag.  You will want to do that instead.

Since there is no "class" or anything on that element, then you could do something like...

```
Dim h1 As HtmlElementCollection = Nothing
    h1 = W.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each h1Element as HtmlElement in h1
        Dim NameStr As String = h1Element.GetAttribute("href")
        If ((NameStr IsNot Nothing) And (NameStr.Length <> 0)) Then 
            h1Element.InvokeMember("Click")
```

Comment: m.facebook.com/browse/likes?id=1026395497374065

</ div > </ div > </ div > < div class = "fu" id = "m_more_item" > < a href = "/ Tarama / seviyor / id = 1026395497374065 & amp;? start = 30 & amp; refid = 53" > < açıklıklı > Di ğ erlerini G ö r </ yayılma > </ a > </ div > </ div > </ div > </ div > </ div > </ div > </ div > </ body > </ html >
Ben "diğerlerini Gör" butonuna tıklayın istiyorum

Code verdi işe yaramadı :(

Ben isteyenler almak istiyorum.

Comment: I want to "Diğerlerini Gör" button click

Code did not work that you gave :(

I want to get those who like.

Comment: @eqiz can you undelete that other answer just for a second?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = Nothing

For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")

            If Element.GetAttribute("id") = "m_more_item" And Element.OuterHtml.Contains("Diğerlerini Gör") Then
                Element.InvokeMember("click")
            End If

        Next
```