# Why am I getting a NullReferenceException with this code?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, nullreferenceexception

I have this code here in my program:

```
foreach (HtmlElement chat in wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
{
    if (chat != null)
    {
        if (chat.InnerText.Equals("Chat"))
        {
            chat.InvokeMember("Click");
            loggedIn = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Once it gets to the `if(chat.InnerText.Equals("Chat"))` it throws a NullReferenceException Error as shown in the ScreenShot below:

[image: Error Code]

Does anyone know why it is giving me that? I even put the `if (chat != null)` code in there, and it still throws it.

This is the website code:

```
<div class="ContentTab">
    Chat
</div>
```

Comment: `chat` is not null but `chat.InnerText` is.

Comment: chat could be an autoclosing tag, then have no inner text. Dunno :D

Comment: The use of `Equals()` in this context looks like a Java-ism. Use the equality operator instead, so you won't end up invoking a method on a `null` reference.

Answer (score 2):

Chat.InnerText is null, even though Chat isn't. Try this:

```
foreach (HtmlElement chat in wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
{
        if (chat != null && chat.InnerText != null && chat.InnerText.Equals("Chat"))
        {
            chat.InvokeMember("Click");
            loggedIn = true;
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Trying that... Thanks

Comment: Didn't work... This is the website code: `<div class="ContentTab">Chat</div>` Do you know how to click it? Because that code isn't working.

Comment: You still got the null reference exception?

Comment: No, I didn't get the error, but it doesn't click...

Comment: So it did solve the issue you asked about. You are now onto a different issue... It didn't click because InnerText is null so it wouldn't fail the if condition

Comment: Yes... Do you know how to get it to click?

Comment: @JackNelson: Try to check for the class `ContentTab`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436116/how-to-select-a-class-by-getelementbyclass-and-click-on-it-programmically

Comment: There are like 10 different tabs, that are all called content tab... The only way to tell them apart is by the inner text

Answer (score 2):

The property `InnerText` of `chat` variable is null

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    if (chat.InnerText == "Chat")
    {
        chat.InvokeMember("Click");
        loggedIn = true;
        break;
    }
```

I believe that .Equals checks object similarity, and operator == checks reference equality.

Comment: Strings are a special case. `==` compares them by value, not by reference, even though they're reference types.

Answer (score 1):

you can try checking the object itself its empty
try this

```
foreach (HtmlElement chat in wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
{
    if (chat != null && (!chat.isEmpty())&& chat!="")
    {
        if (chat.InnerText.Equals("Chat"))
        {
            chat.InvokeMember("Click");
            loggedIn = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```