# Press a button using class names in c# dom

Tags: c#, dom

So basically I want to press a button in a website and i dont know what code to use. The **HTML** line looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="Free" data-date="1498544574">Click Here</a>
```

I want the program to click on that Free Button using DOM. I tried this :

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByClassName("free").InvokeMember("click");
```

But for some reason the GetElementByClassName is highlighted (in visual studio 2015)

**I cannot change the HTML since the website is not mine.**

Answer (score 0):

It's highlighted cause there is no function GetElementByClassName in WebBrowser.Document!

Look at this, maybe it would help you:

[How to select a class by GetElementByClass and click on it programmically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436116/how-to-select-a-class-by-getelementbyclass-and-click-on-it-programmically)